# The sense of Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc

What is the main advantage of the Spring framework?

Is it loosing dependence between objects ? We can setup the values of fields in xml files but what is the difference between initializing these fields with help xml or simply in the java code?

Here is very similar question: [What exactly is Spring Framework for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061717/what-exactly-is-spring-for)
Is there any other advantage ?

Comment: A forum is a much suitable place to ask this question.

Comment: Spring has a whole lot of modules that perform different tasks. The primary advantage of the core Context system is dependency injection (where your classes get the fields they need autowired instead of looking them up manually). XML configuration is actually old-style now, and the new JavaConfig system is all I use.

Comment: @chrylis what does exactly mean JavaConfig ? Configuration in java code by spring annotations ?

Comment: @MrPhi JavaConfig was the working name of using annotations and code to set up the context, with `@Configuration`, `@Bean`, and the rest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is Spring for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061717/what-exactly-is-spring-for)

Comment: @chrylis so does it mean that http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/ is out of date ?

Comment: @MrPhi That's from 4 years ago, updated 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big topic but I'll try to explain Inversion Of Control

An example: 
Say that you have a project where you need to communicate with different third parties to whom you need to communicate, 
but the details differ.

The best way would be to define a generic interface

```
public interface ThirdPartyConnector{
    public String sendRequest(String data);
}
```

Implementation for your first third party could look:

```
public class FirstThirdPartyConnector implements ThirdPartyConnector{
    public String sendRequest(String data){
    //implementation details
    }
}
```

Your second third party:

```
public class SecondThirdPartyConnector implements ThirdPartyConnector{
    public String sendRequest(String data){
    //implementation details
    }
}
```

And so on...

Now, in your java code, when communicating with these third parties, 
you never instantiate them with the `new` keyword, you work with `ThirdPartyConnector` interface.
This way, during compile time you don't specifiy in your code which `ThirdPartyConnector` to use.

You do that in XML.

And not changing Java code to switch implementation is crucial in big systems because of complexity in maintenance. And you don't need to touch previous implementations to implement new third parties.