# Payara Server Failure

Tags: connection-pooling, netbeans-8, application-server, payara

I have a problem here with me at the moment, regarding [application servers](http://www.itpro.co.uk/strategy/29643/what-is-an-application-server). I want to build an app. that connects to the database using [Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061717/what-exactly-is-spring-framework-for) (not [Spring Boot](https://dzone.com/articles/7-things-to-know-getting-started-with-spring-boot)).

I first started with glassfish, in which I could not create a [connection pool](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/jdbc-jdbc-connection-pooling). So, someone recommended that I use [Payara Server](https://www.azul.com/resources/success-stories/payara/) for pooling.

These is what I did:

1. Because I did not have Payara Plugins in Netbeans, I downloaded and plugged them in.
2. Created a server in Netbeans using a simple GUI (click-away)
3. During creation, Netbeans required me to select/download a server. I told Netbeans to download it for me (I selected this version to be downloaded: [Payara 4.1.1.161](https://docs.payara.fish/release-notes/release-notes-161.html)).
4. The server was then created successfully.

When I start the server, I receive the following error:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to retry with the most recent version of Payara Server, which is 5.181, released in February 2018.

The version 4.1.1.161 is 2 years old.

If the version 5.181 isn't available in the Netbeans GUI, just download if from here https://www.payara.fish/all_downloads, unzip on the disk and point Netbeans to its location.

Answer (score -1):

I would also recommend using the latest version of Payara Server, but I think that what is causing the error here could be a JVM option which has a space in it (e.g. `- Xmx` rather than `-Xmx`).

It looks like Java is trying to interpret a single `-` as a JVM option.